# Learning blockchain terminology

Tags: blockchain

What are some resources someone new to this asset class and crytocurrencies can use to understand the language and terminology used in describing it?  Like any area of interest, understanding the terminology is both the barrier and the key to being involved in it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[TokenMarket provides a knowledge base covering the basic smart contract and digital asset terminology](https://tokenmarket.net/what-is/).

Furthermore if you are new to the topic and you want to learn it, it makes sense to take an online course, like ones offered by Coursera and Udemy.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to get started learning about digital assets and trading cryptocurrency is to follow cryptocurrency channels on Telegram. Here's a list to get you started:

#### Currencies/Blockchains Telegram Groups:

`@BitcoinCore (BTC)
@BitSharesDEX (BTS)
@Counterparty (XCP)
@DashDigitalCash (DASH)
@DigiByteCoin (DGB)
@DigiByteRU (DGB Russian):triangular_flag_on_post:
@TheDogeHouse (DOGE)
@EtcRussia (ETC Russia)
@EthClassic (ETC Main Group)
@FactomFCT (FCT)
@KryptonCoin (KR):triangular_flag_on_post:
@Litecoin (LTC) 
@MaidSafeCoin (MAID)
@Monero (XMR)
@NemRed (XEM):triangular_flag_on_post:
@NXTCommunity (NXT)
@OmniLayer (OMNI)
@RippleXRP (XRP)
@XRPITA (XRP Italy):triangular_flag_on_post:
@ShadowCash (SDC)
@Siacoin (SC)
@Steemit (STEEM Russian):triangular_flag_on_post:
@Steem_en (STEEM English):triangular_flag_on_post:
@StorjProject (SJCX)
@Synereo (AMP)
@ZCashco (ZCash)`

Crypto Groups: 
@BFU_Cryptochat (Crypto Ukraine)
@BitcoinChat 
@C2Trade 
@CryptoMining (Mining Discussion)
@CriptoNoticias (Spanish) :triangular_flag_on_post:
@GettCoinToday (Russian)
:round_pushpin:@TheCoinFarm (Altcoin Chat):round_pushpin:
:round_pushpin:WhaleClub largest Crypto Group::round_pushpin:
:round_pushpin:http://telegram.whaleclub.io:round_pushpin:

Prediction Markets:
@AugurProject
@GnosisPM

Technology:
@LightningNetwork
@PeerToPeer
@RSKSmart (Rootstock)
@Segwit
@Sidechains
@SmartContracts
@TrezorTalk:triangular_flag_on_post:
@WingsChat (DAO)

Others:
@Avalbit (Bitcoin Association ES):triangular_flag_on_post:
@CoinTelegraphES (Review ES):triangular_flag_on_post:
@CryptoCharity (Give Back :)
@BTCFork (Movement) 
@ICOCountdown (ICO Discussion)
@ICOIntel (ICO Discussion)
@Sportsbet (Degenerate Gamblers)